# Why Apache Traffic Server does not cache https content even though SSL termination has been setup?

Tags: ssl, termination, apache-traffic-server, forward-proxy

I'm using ATS as forward proxy. The http content cache without any problem, but the https content just don't work. Here are my configures.

```
# records.config
CONFIG proxy.config.http.server_ports STRING 8125 8443:ssl
CONFIG proxy.config.http.cache.required_headers INT 0
CONFIG proxy.config.url_remap.remap_required INT 0
CONFIG proxy.config.reverse_proxy.enabled INT 0
CONFIG proxy.config.ssl.server.cert.path STRING /usr/local/etc/ssl/
CONFIG proxy.config.ssl.server.private_key.path STRING /usr/local/etc/ssl/
CONFIG proxy.config.ssl.client.certification_level INT 0
```

```
# ssl_multicert.config
dest_ip=*      ssl_cert_name=fullchain-from-letsencrypt.pem ssl_key_name=key-from-letsencrypt.pem
```

In which `fullchain-from-letsencrypt.pem` and `key-from-letsencrypt.pem` was generated with certbot. This should make SSL termination works, but it's not.

```bash
export http_proxy=http://ats.domain:8125
export https_proxy=https://ats.domain:8443;

# http works fine.
wget https://releases.ubuntu.com/jammy/ubuntu-22.04.2-live-server-amd64.iso.zsync

# https will not cache, and got error messages.
wget https://releases.ubuntu.com/jammy/ubuntu-22.04.2-live-server-amd64.iso.zsync
```

And I got this error message.

```
--2023-08-04 10:38:30--  https://releases.ubuntu.com/jammy/ubuntu-22.04.2-live-server-amd64.iso.zsync
Resolving ats.domain (ats.domain)... 10.147.19.193
Connecting to ats.domain (ats.domain)|10.147.19.193|:8443... connected.
Failed reading proxy response: Success
Retrying.
```

`curl` fetch the file properly both http and https.

```bash
# http works fine
curl http://releases.ubuntu.com/jammy/ubuntu-22.04.2-live-server-amd64.iso.zsync > /dev/null

# https not cache without error
curl https://releases.ubuntu.com/jammy/ubuntu-22.04.2-live-server-amd64.iso.zsync > /dev/null
```

But https does not cache according to the log.

```bash
traffic_logcat -f /usr/local/var/log/trafficserver/squid.blog

1691116320.693 6 TCP_HIT/200 3859845 GET http://releases.ubuntu.com/jammy/ubuntu-22.04.2-live-server-amd64.iso.zsync - NONE/- application/x-iso9660-image
1691116855.993 7849 TCP_MISS/200 105 CONNECT releases.ubuntu.com:443/ - DIRECT/releases.ubuntu.com -
```

And this is the curl log

```
* Uses proxy env variable https_proxy == 'https://ats.domain:8443'
* Connected to ats.domain (10.147.19.193) port 8443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
*  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
} [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
} [512 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
{ [122 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
{ [25 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
{ [3971 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
{ [264 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
{ [52 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
} [1 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
} [52 bytes data]
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
* Proxy certificate:
*  subject: CN=ats.domain
*  start date: Aug  2 02:37:07 2023 GMT
*  expire date: Oct 31 02:37:06 2023 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "ats.domain" matched cert's "ats.domain"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Let's Encrypt; CN=R3
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* allocate connect buffer!
* Establish HTTP proxy tunnel to releases.ubuntu.com:443
} [5 bytes data]
> CONNECT releases.ubuntu.com:443 HTTP/1.1
> Host: releases.ubuntu.com:443
> User-Agent: curl/7.74.0
> Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
> 
{ [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
{ [281 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
{ [281 bytes data]
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Fri, 04 Aug 2023 03:39:37 GMT
< Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
< Server: ATS/9.2.1
< 
* Proxy replied 200 to CONNECT request
* CONNECT phase completed!
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
*  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
} [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
} [512 bytes data]
* CONNECT phase completed!
* CONNECT phase completed!
{ [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
{ [122 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
{ [25 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
{ [2622 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
{ [264 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
{ [52 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
} [1 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
} [52 bytes data]
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=releases.ubuntu.com
*  start date: Jul 13 21:45:45 2023 GMT
*  expire date: Oct 11 21:45:44 2023 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "releases.ubuntu.com" matched cert's "releases.ubuntu.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Let's Encrypt; CN=R3
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
} [5 bytes data]
> GET /jammy/ubuntu-22.04.2-live-server-amd64.iso.zsync HTTP/1.1
> Host: releases.ubuntu.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.74.0
> Accept: */*
> 
{ [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
{ [281 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
{ [297 bytes data]
* old SSL session ID is stale, removing
{ [5 bytes data]
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Fri, 04 Aug 2023 03:39:37 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)
< Last-Modified: Thu, 23 Feb 2023 17:47:38 GMT
< ETag: "3ae46d-5f5619bd762ba"
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Content-Length: 3859565
< Content-Type: application/x-iso9660-image
< 
{ [5 bytes data]
* Connection #0 to host ats.domain ⇦ intact
```

Are there anything that I missed in the configuration for SSL termination?

Answer (score 0):

In you http case, curl used the GET method (`1691116320.693 6 TCP_HIT/200 3859845 GET`), but, in the https, it used CONNECT (squid.log + curl log -- the 'Uses proxy env variable https_proxy...' probably does that?). In the latter case, your ATS will not see the object nor headers -- its more like a tunnel between curl and the end destination. If you follow the curl log, your ATS gets the request lines starting with ">" from `CONNECT releases.ubuntu.com:443 HTTP/1.1` to the `> Proxy-...`.

Can you try: `curl "https://releases.ubuntu.com/jammy/ubuntu-22.04.2-live-server-amd64.iso.zsyn" --connect-to ::$ATS_IP -D- -o/dev/null` ... thinking this would force it to be a GET, and perhaps allow further troubleshooting.

Comment: Thanks. I tried, but it would have certificate issue. Here are part of the logs of curl.Traffic Server has no log.

```
* SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name 'releases.ubuntu.com'
curl: (60) SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name 'releases.ubuntu.com'
More details here: https://curl.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

Comment: By adding `-k` to make curl ignore certificate check, the file can be download. But still not cache. I got this log from Traffic Server.

```
1691484910.903 929 TCP_MISS/404 462 GET https://releases.ubuntu.com/jammy/ubuntu-22.04.2-live-server-amd64.iso.zsyn - DIRECT/releases.ubuntu.com text/html
```